# Cannot automatically insert bibliography in Texworks

Tags: bibtex, mactex, texworks

I've just installed MacTeX and used TeXworks. However, every time a want to insert a new BibTeX record, I have to manually execute BibTeX command in a terminal and then run Typeset in TeXworks, otherwise I will receive 'citation undefined' warning and a citation is displayed as '[?]'. I want to ask for a way to manually execution all required commands for inserting bib just by clicking on Typeset in TeXworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using TeXworks with MacTeX, there's no need to run BibTeX from a Terminal prompt.

After running `pdfLaTeX` once from inside TeXworks -- presumably by clicking on the black arrow inside the green circle, right? -- you need to click on the drop-down menu to the immediate right of the "Typeset" button and select `BibTeX` from the options that present themselves. After running `BibTeX` once, run `pdfLaTeX` twice more.

Comment: Thanks, your solution work for me. But, is there another way which doesn't involve with pressing them same button many times, i.e. I'm looking for a way to just push a button once, if there is any exists?

Comment: @LongThai - In a normal editing session, it's usually not necessary to run `BibTeX` very often; in such situations, there's no need to keep switching back and forth between running pdfLaTeX and BibTeX. However, if that's not the way you normally work, I suggest to you take a look at the [arara](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) package and its many capabilities. You'll also need to add `arara` as an option to the dropdown menu. `arara` can be configured extremely flexibly.